# Is it safe to uninstall Asus Eee Dock?

Tags: eee-pc

Is it safe to uninstall the Asus Eee Dock? (http://techinstyle.tv/products/what-is-the-asus-eee-dock/)

There is a program called Eee Docking 3.8.3, which I guess has to be uninstalled. But is this safe / will the Asus including camera still work without it?

Comment: I am going to guess this application is like Logitechs software.  Where its possible to install the drivers for the camera, and when a peice of software ( i.e. Skype ) uses the camera, it will hook into special controls for the camera.  You can install it provided the you have other software to control the camera with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 100% safe.  You may need an alternate program to use video-chat, Google Voice or Skype would work.